# Euler Lagrange equation for an objective function with integral

Tags: optimization, euler-lagrange-equation, dynamic-programming

I came across a dynamic optimization problem. I looked at several references, but none of them had an example of my problem. It seems to be related to Euler-Lagrange, but the inclusion of integral makes me a headache.

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-rt}f(c(t))\,e^{-\left(\int_0^t c(h)\,dh\right)t}dt $$

Note that $f(t) = u(t)+w-p\,c(t),$ where $u(t)$ is a concave function with $w$ as endowment and $p$ as a price.

I am maximizing this objective function with a function $c(t).$ Shall I use a chain rule to take a derivative of the integral with $c(t)$ and $d(c(t))/dt$ for both? or only for $c(t)?$  Thank you

---

My second question supposes that we take
$$C(t)=\int_0^t c(h)\,dh. $$
Then we can reformulate the objective function as
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-rt}f(\dot{C}(t))\,e^{-t\,C(t)}\,dt. $$
Then the Lagrangian is
$$L(t;C,\dot{C})=e^{-rt}f(\dot{C}(t))\,e^{-t\,C(t)} $$
with initial condition $C(0)=0.$

Comment: Do you know what $f$ is?

Comment: Could you at least shortly enlighten me the logic behind using the second calculus of varaitions for the integral of c(h)? Why cannot I take it as F(t) and use chain rule as dF(t)/dt * dt/dc(t) ? It was my first guess.

Comment: In this case, you probably could. The danger is if the derivative shows up. The Euler-Lagrange equations require you to handle that more general case in a particular way.

Comment: I am sorry I don't get it clear. So you mean I could have used my first guess approach? But my solution was way more complicated than yours and on top of that I couldn't disregard that dF(t)/dt * dt/dc'(t) should hold as well.

Comment: Well, if you define $F(t)$ as the integral, then taking the time derivative after you've integrated just means you'll get zero, since you've integrated out $t.$ You would need to take the partial derivative inside the integral to compute $dF/dt.$ Then how do you compute $dt/dc(t)?$ You don't know the dependent of $c$ on $t.$ So, come to think of it, I'm not sure your approach will work after all.

Comment: Ok now I see your point. Thank you very much!

Comment: Comment to the post (v5): Why does the argument for $f$ differ in OP's first eqs, that is, $f(c(t))$ vs. $f(t)$?

Answer (score 1):

The Euler-Lagrange equation for this problem says that, given the integral
$$\int_0^\infty \underbrace{e^{-rt}f(c(t))\,e^{-\left(\int_0^t c(h)\,dh\right)t}}_{=\,L(c,\dot{c};t)}dt,$$
the extremum is given by
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial c}-\frac{d}{dt}\,\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{c}}=0. $$
But now $\dot{c}$ does not appear in $L,$ so this simplifies down to
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial c}=0.$$
We compute
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial c}
&=e^{-rt}\bigg[\underbrace{f'(c(t))\,e^{-\left(\int_0^t c(h)\,dh\right)t}
+f(c(t))\,\frac{d}{dc}e^{-\left(\int_0^t c(h)\,dh\right)t}}_{\text{product rule}}\bigg]\\
&=e^{-rt}\bigg[f'(c(t))\,e^{-\left(\int_0^t c(h)\,dh\right)t}
-tf(c(t))\,\underbrace{e^{-\left(\int_0^t c(h)\,dh\right)t}\,\frac{d}{dc}\left(\int_0^t c(h)\,dh\right)}_{\text{chain rule}}\bigg]\\
&=e^{-rt}e^{-\left(\int_0^t c(h)\,dh\right)t}\left[f'(c(t))
-tf(c(t))\,\frac{d}{dc}\left(\int_0^t c(h)\,dh\right)\right].
\end{align*}

Now the expression $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dc}\left(\int_0^t c(h)\,dh\right)$ is a bit problematic. To calculate this, we actually need to use the [Calculus of Variations again](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative), with a different $\tilde L=c(h).$ Then 
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dc}\left(\int_0^t c(h)\,dh\right)
&=\frac{\partial\tilde L}{\partial c}-\frac{d}{dh}\,\frac{\partial\tilde L}{\partial\dot{c}}\\
&=1.
\end{align*}
Hence,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial c}
&=e^{-rt}e^{-\left(\int_0^t c(h)\,dh\right)t}\left[f'(c(t))
-tf(c(t))\right]\\
&=0.
\end{align*}
This implies that
\begin{align*}
f'(c(t))-tf(c(t))&=0.
\end{align*}
The form of $f$ is $f(t)=u(t)+w-p\,c(t),$ and note that, according to our calculations, $f'(c(t))=df/dc.$ We see that $df/dc=-p,$ so that this equation becomes
$$-p-t(u(t)+w-p\,c(t))=0. $$
Solving for $c(t)$ yields
$$c(t)=\frac{p+t u(t)+t w}{p t}. $$

As for the reformulation, we can write
\begin{align*}
L&=f(\dot{C}(t))\,e^{-t(r+C(t))}\\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial C}&=-tf(\dot{C}(t))\,e^{-t(r+C(t))}\\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{C}}&=f'(\dot{C}(t))\,e^{-t(r+C(t))}\\
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{C}}&=f''(\dot{C}(t))\,\ddot{C}(t)\,e^{-t(r+C(t))}+f'(\dot{C}(t))\,e^{-t(r+C(t))}\,(-t\dot{C}(t)-r-C(t)).
\end{align*}
These are the ingredients for the EL equation: $L_C-d\!\left(L_{\dot{C}}\right)/dt=0:$
\begin{align*}
-tf(\dot{C}(t))\,e^{-t(r+C(t))}-f''(\dot{C}(t))\,\ddot{C}(t)\,e^{-t(r+C(t))}-f'(\dot{C}(t))\,e^{-t(r+C(t))}\,(-t\dot{C}(t)-r-C(t))&=0\\
-tf(\dot{C}(t))-f''(\dot{C}(t))\,\ddot{C}(t)-f'(\dot{C}(t))\,(-t\dot{C}(t)-r-C(t))&=0.
\end{align*}
Then you would need to substitute in to what $f$ is, and try to solve for $C.$ It all looks rather complicated.

Comment: Sorry, can I ask you one more question? why can't I change integral as to C(t) and c(t) as a C'(t) and then make Euler Lagrange equation as L(t, C(t), C'(t))? In this case it does not give the same answear.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question; could you please rephrase?

Comment: I added on the question. Thank you!

Comment: I was looking forward to your answer. Thank you very much. So are you saying that the two Euler-Lagrange equations lead to the same optimal path? As you said, the reformulation version EL was extremely complicated, but the first one was too simpler than I expected.

Comment: No, I haven't said that, though they should. That is, if I differentiate the $C(t)$ from the reformulated version, I should get the $c(t)$ function from the previous version.

Comment: Ok. I will check myself. Thanks for the long conversation! I really appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell me the technique that you have used in the original version, taking another calculus of variations? It would be great to study on it.

Comment: I used Calculus of Variations, particularly the Euler-Lagrange equation, plus regular calculus for the product rule and chain rules of differentiation.